# Using Prolog to compute the GCD of a polynomial

Tags: prolog, polynomial-math, greatest-common-divisor

The title kind of says it all. I'm looking to compute the GCD of two polynomials. Is there any way this can be done in Prolog? If so, what's a good starting point? Specifically, I'm having trouble with how to implement polynomial division using Prolog.

Edit to include example input and output:

Example input:

```
?-  GCD(x^2 + 7x + 6, x2 − 5x − 6, X).
```

Example output:

```
X = x + 1.
```

**Solution**

On the off chance that someone else needs to do this, here's my final solution:

```
tail([_|Tail], Tail).
head([Head | _], Head).

norm(Old, N, New) :- 
    length(Tail, N),
    append(New, Tail, Old).
norm(Old, N, []) :-
    length(Old, L),
    N > L.

mult_GCD(List, GCD) :- length(List, L),
    L > 2, tail(List, Tail),
    mult_GCD(Tail, GCD).
mult_GCD([H | T], GCD) :-
    length(T, L),
    L == 1, head(T, N),
    gcd(H, N, GCD).

lead(List, List) :-
    length(List, L),
    L == 1.
lead([0 | Tail], Out) :- 
    !, lead(Tail, Out).
lead([Head | Tail], [Head | Tail]) :- Head =\= 0.

poly_deg([], 0).
poly_deg(F, D) :-
    lead(F, O),
    length(O, N),
    D is N - 1.

poly_red([0], [0]).
poly_red(Poly, Out) :-
    mult_GCD(Poly, GCD),
    scal_div(Poly, GCD, Out).

poly_sub(Poly,[],Poly) :- Poly = [_|_].
poly_sub([],Poly,Poly).
poly_sub([P1_head|P1_rest], [P2_head|P2_rest], [PSub_head|PSub_rest]) :-
    PSub_head is P1_head-P2_head,
    poly_sub(P1_rest, P2_rest, PSub_rest).

scal_prod([],_Sc,[]).
scal_prod([Poly_head|Poly_rest], Sc, [Prod_head|Prod_rest]) :-
    Prod_head is Poly_head*Sc,
    scal_prod(Poly_rest, Sc, Prod_rest).

scal_div([],_,[]).
scal_div([Poly_head|Poly_rest], Sc, [Prod_head|Prod_rest]) :-
    Prod_head is Poly_head / Sc,
    scal_div(Poly_rest, Sc, Prod_rest).

poly_div(Num, Den, OutBuild, Out) :-
    poly_deg(Num, X),
    poly_deg(Den, Y),
    X < Y,
    Out = OutBuild.
poly_div(INum, IDen, OutBuild, Out) :-
    lead(INum, [NumHead | NumTail]), lead(IDen, [DenHead | DenTail]),
    Q is NumHead / DenHead,
    append(OutBuild, [Q], Out1),
    append([DenHead], DenTail, DenNorm), append([NumHead], NumTail, Num),
    scal_prod(DenNorm, Q, DenXQ),
    poly_sub(Num, DenXQ, N),
    poly_div(N, IDen, Out1, Out).

poly_mod(Num, Den, Out) :-
    poly_deg(Num, X), poly_deg(Den, Y),
    X < Y,
    lead(Num, Out1),
    poly_red(Out1, Out2),
    lead(Out2, Out).
poly_mod(INum, IDen, Out) :-
    lead(INum, [NumHead | NumTail]), lead(IDen, [DenHead | DenTail]),
    Q is NumHead / DenHead,
    append([DenHead], DenTail, DenNorm), append([NumHead], NumTail, Num),
    scal_prod(DenNorm, Q, DenXQ),
    poly_sub(Num, DenXQ, N),
    poly_mod(N, IDen, Out).

poly_gcd(X, Y, X):- poly_deg(Y, O), O == 0, !.
poly_gcd(Y, X, X):- poly_deg(Y, O), O == 0, !.
poly_gcd(X, Y, D):- poly_deg(X, Xd), poly_deg(Y, Yd), Xd > Yd, !, poly_mod(X, Y, Z), poly_gcd(Y, Z, D).
poly_gcd(X, Y, D):- poly_mod(Y, X, Z), poly_gcd(X, Z, D).

gcd(X, Y, Z) :-
    X < 0, X > Y, !,
    X1 is X - Y,
    gcd(-X, Y, Z).
gcd(X, Y, Z) :-
    Y < 0, Y >= X, !,
    Y1 is Y - X,
    gcd(X, -Y, Z).
gcd(X, 0, X).
gcd(0, Y, Y).
gcd(X, Y, Z) :-
    X > Y, Y > 0,
    X1 is X - Y,
    gcd(Y, X1, Z).
gcd(X, Y, Z) :-
    X =< Y, X > 0,
    Y1 is Y - X,
    gcd(X, Y1, Z).
gcd(X, Y, Z) :-
    X > Y, Y < 0,
    X1 is X + Y,
    gcd(Y, X1, Z).
gcd(X, Y, Z) :-
    X =< Y, X < 0,
    Y1 is Y + X,
    gcd(X, Y1, Z).
```

Comment: Yes, it should be able to handle any exponent. It's entirely possible that it's not really possible in Prolog, I just wanted someone who's actually good at Prolog to tell me that.

Comment: Prolog is a general purpose programming language. If you can do it with a computer, you should be able to do it with Prolog. First, try to search and find if your problem hasn't been already solved. Then, if not, find an algorithm that does what you need, and try to implement it in Prolog. If you run into a problem you cannot solve yourself, show your code, explain the problem, explain what it is that you couldn't troubleshoot on your own. I am not going to vote this question for closing but it is quite ripe for it as it stands.

Comment: My problem is that I don't really know how to start. I have an version which  computes GCD for integers, but I don't know where to start with polynomial division. This is not my first time here, I know to search before asking, and there is really nothing on this topic online as far as I can tell.

Comment: Well, the wikipedia page on polynomial gcd has pseudo code for doing Euclidean division of polynomials and shows how to use it for finding the gcd of the polynomials. Have you tried to read the article?

Comment: The point here is that although this is certainly not your intention, the question as it reads right now is just a description of a task and "give me teh codez". If you made any attempt to implement say polynomial division and come up with a more specific question, I am sure you'll eventually get help.

Comment: Yes I have read this article. Unfortunately it seems to assume polynomial division, exactly the thing I am having trouble with. Again, my problem is that I don't know how to start with this, if I had some code written, I would post it, but as it is, I can't even think of a way to go about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is meant as a push in the right direction.

First, forget for a moment that you need to parse an expression like `x^2 + 7x + 6`; this isn't even a proper term in Prolog yet. If you tried to write it on the top level, you will get an error:

```
?- Expr = x^2 + 7x + 6.
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: Expr = x^2 + 
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: 7x + 6 .
```

Prolog doesn't know how to deal with the `7x` you have there. Parsing the expression is a question of its own, and maybe it is easier if you assumed you have already parsed it and gotten a representation that looks for example like this:

```
[6, 7, 1]
```

Similarly, `x^2 − 5x − 6` becomes:

```
[-6, -5, 1]
```

and to represent 0 you would use the empty list:

```
[]
```

Now, take a look at the [algorithm at the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division). It uses `deg` for the degree and `lc` for the leading coefficient. With the list representation above, you can define those as:

> The degree is one less then the length of the list holding the coefficients.

```
poly_deg(F, D) :-
    length(F, N),
    D is N - 1.
```

> The leading coefficient is the last element of the list.

```
poly_lc(F, C) :-
    last(F, C).
```

You also need to be able to do simple arithmetic with polynomials. Using the definitions on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_arithmetic), we see that for example adding `[]` and `[1]` should give you `[1]`, multiplying `[-2, 2]` with `[1, -3, 1]` should give you `[-2, 8, -8, 2]`. A [precursory search](https://www.google.com/search?q=product+of+polynomials+prolog) gave me [this question here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936560/multiply-two-polynomials-in-prolog). Using the predicates defined there:

```
?- poly_prod([-2,2], [1, -3, 1], P).
P = [-2.0, 8.0, -8.0, 2] .

?- poly_sum([], [1], S).
S = [1].
```

From here on, it should be possible for you to try and implement polynomial division as outlined in the Wiki article I linked above. If you get into more trouble, you should edit your question or ask a new one.

Comment: Well now I feel a bit silly. Had I tried to implement this in any other language I probably would have thought of using lists, but somehow this never occurred to me. This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @bendl I am quite happy that this actually helped you :) Good luck

Comment: One comment: in your code 

poly_deg(F, D) :- length(P, N), D is N - 1.

Should be 

poly_deg(F, D) :- length(F, N), D is N - 1.

Unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @bendl yes, that's a typo, well spotted