# Very small floats causing Overflow errors in Prolog

Tags: prolog, floating-accuracy, swi-prolog

The program I'm writing is using floats, but with very large numbers seems to be creating floats which should resolve to 0, but are actually very very small decimals. These are causing overflows and throwing an error. Is there something I can do to avoid this?

Comment: Floating point numbers are just approximations with several flaws. See wikipedia or such. Compare with small eps for equality.

Comment: I'm aware of the problems associated with floating points in general, but I don't know how to work around them in Prolog. Can you expand on what you mean by small eps?

Comment: A  check for being zero actually better be comparing against ±0.0001(`abs(X) < 0.0001`) or  such, but if you are aware of the problems, you are asking moresophisticated solutions - I do not have. http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=floatsyntax (nan, infinity)

Comment: Could you give us your code and a simple example that  in which the above problem occurs ??

Comment: The full code is available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711616/using-prolog-to-compute-the-gcd-of-a-polynomial/39740862?noredirect=1) and I believe most inputs of high degree polynomials are causing errors. I encountered an error with a polynomial of degree 20.

Comment: Please give us a reproducible tiny example