# Expressing an equation in prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, equation

Conjunction and negation tables are given in facts. Write a predicate: "solution to AX^2 + BX + C = 0 is X". All the values are boolean, 1 - true, 0 - false. 
Fact tables are like this:

```
c(true, true, true).
c(true, false, false).
c(false, true, false).
c(false, false, false).
n(true, false).
n(false, true).
```

I have no idea what to do and where to start.

Comment: You could represent your equation as a list of coefficients, better start from the end: `[C, B, A]`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39740862/1812457). How the conjunction and negation fit into this is not very clear; you need to add more detail to your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (please at least provide an example of an input and an output)

Comment: The task is:
Conjunction and negation tables are given in facts. Write a predicate: "solution to AX^2 + BX + C = 0 is X".

Comment: Boris has it.  If you want the top line to be way too easy to read, `solve(A,timesXSquared,plus,B,timesX,plus,C,is,X)` will work.  ...but what do conjunction tables have to do with it?  It's apparent that n means negation and c means or, but... what does that have to do with the quadratic equation?

Comment: The comment by @TopologicalSort picks on the same as mine. Still no idea how the two topics in your question are connected. And please edit your question, don't add details in comments.

Comment: And one more thing, since this looks very much like homework: why are you not asking your instructor for help? Whoever gave this as an assignment must know better than any of us what exactly is expected. You yourself must have access to the context in which this "task" appears, but you are not sharing any of that context in the question.

Comment: @Boris I asked, basically all the values values are boolean, and + is disjunction, * is conjunction.

Comment: @RičardasMikelionis You really need to update your question instead of putting details in the comments!

Comment: If + is disjunction and * is conjunction, what is the 0? True? False? Or is "Expr = 0" a way to denote a logical equivalence or something of that sort?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I wrote a predicate for disjunction using given facts, and rewrote the equation using conjunction and disjunction.

```
conjunction(true, true, true).
conjunction(true, false, false).
conjunction(false, true, false).
conjunction(false, false, false).
negation(true, false).
negation(false, true).

disjunction(Bool, Bool2, Result):-negation(Bool, NBool),
                                  negation(Bool2, NBool2),
                                  conjunction(NBool, NBool2, Conj),
                                  negation(Conj, Result).

%X^2 is X*X in this case X^X whis is always equal to X.
equation(A,B,C,X):-conjunction(A, X, AtimesX2),               %A*(X*X)
                   conjunction(B, X, BtimesX),                %B*X
                   disjunction(AtimesX2, BtimesX, AX2plusBX), %A*X^2+B*X
                   disjunction(AX2plusBX, C, Res),            %A*X^2+B*X+C
                   Res = false.                               %Checking if
                                                              %A*X^2+B*X+C is equal to 0
```

Comment: Since `Res = false`, you can use `false` where you are currently using `Res`.